# Font Appears different

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode

Hi I am using Sanskrit2003 font and it appears with additional circle in TeXWorks, just to verify I copied it to MS Word & open office  and it appeared fine in word. 
I am attaching an image to show you the difference. I am not sure why same font behaves differently in two applications.

I want it to appear in TeXworks the way it appears in MS word. Should I be using any special package
I am running on Texlive2010, ubuntu 10.10 and Texworks.

thanks for your help
[image]

Comment: give a short example file

Comment: how does it look on the final pdf when you compile?

Comment: this is how it is appearing in TeXWorks      \lhead{अथ अजन्त पुल्ँलिङ्ग} and it is appearing just like that in the final Pdf.

Comment: As far as I can tell (not knowing anything about Devanagari), there seem to be problems with applying multiple combining characters to a single letter in the Devanagari script in Pango (the text rendering engine used in Gnome) and XeTeX. If this is indeed how characters should be typed then I would consider this a bug.

Comment: @Caramdir - I think its more like what people prefer to see the way to avoid this circle and in between is this "पुल्लिँङ्ग"  which is also very much acceptable. I also wrote to the people who wrote the Itranslator software to convert phonetic english text to Devanagari. Have not heard from them. Sorry for no TeX related question.